# Hiding/showing div by selecting dropdown and button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

i want to select a value from my dropdown, and then, when i click a button, it hides certain div and show another div. I'm baffled on how to achieved this. so i have two div.

```
<div id="div1"> some content </div>
<div id="div2"> some content </div>
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Reference, ViewBag.ISharedUI as SelectList, "-- REFERENCE TYPE -- SHOW ALL", new { @id = "testID" })
```

and here is my button.

```
<input type="submit" value="Filter" name="Command" class="btn btn-default" onclick="abc()" />
```

and this is my function. I try to do it,

```
function abc() {
    if ('#testID' != 1) {
        $('#div1').show();
        $('#div2').hide();
    } else if (testID != 2) {
        $('#div1').show();
        $('#div2').hide();
    } else { 
        $('#div1').hide();
        $('#div2').hide();
    }
}
```

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: @MarkC. it is the id i assigned for my dropdown.

Comment: You button is a submit button so the form as soon as the divs are shown or hidden you immediately post and are no longer on the same page (no doubt you code works but it happens so fast you probably don;t see it). Change `<input type="submit"..>` to `<button type="button" ...>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke; yea that works. So anyway, why can't a have a submit button, because certain value in the dropdown, i need it to submit. is it not possible?

Comment: Submitting means you leave the page. Its not clear what your trying to do. If your want to redirect back to the view and have the `<div>` elements shown or hidden based on your selected value, then you need to do that when the page loads.

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes, exactly as you say. its what im trying to do. how do i achieve that when the page load?

Comment: Can post an answer shortly, but I'm confused by you use of `if ('#testID' != 1)`. Do you want to hide both divs initially, but if the value is `"1"`, show the first div, and if the value is `"2"` show the second div?. And are you redirecting back to the GET method or just returning the view in the POST method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80342/discussion-between-kamil-azman-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure with what you want to do with the value from the dropdown input, but it is not too relevant to affecting the state of the divs if you are only interacting with the button to affect the divs.

In terms just hiding the div, you can apply a class "hidden" that hides the element or not with CSS.

Then you can toggle the div and whether or not it appears by clicking on the button with jQuery by adding and removing that hidden class with the toggleClass.

Let me know if you have any more questions.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn").on("click", function() {
    $("#div1").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#div2").toggleClass("hidden");
  })
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<div id="div1"> some content </div>
<div id="div2" class="hidden"> some content </div>

<input type="submit" value="Filter" name="Command" class="btn btn-default" onclick="abc()" />
```